# Long-term predictions

Tags: bayesian, forecasting, prediction

My question might sound a bit vague and probably too broad. It is because I do not expect straight answer. I'm starting a part of my PhD were I need to analyse a long-term prediction of reliability. However, after initial investigation (a.k.a. searching in various database, as well as googling) I have not found any statistical paper analyzing the question of predicting long-term behaviour of a random variable. Of course, long-term is problem-dependent, but I seek some references where questions like "how reasonable are the long-term predictions", "how to compare estimators in long-term predictions", "what methods fail at delivering reasonable long-term predictions", "Bayesian long-term prediction versus frequentist". 
Any comment or reference to a paper on this topic would be of high interest for me.

Comment: I would use a hold-out sample chosen so that the hold-out sample is as "long-term" from the test sample as your estimation goal is. Of course, this supposes that you have long historical data.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you try to define what "long-term" means for you, or what kind of behaviors you are interested in. For example it is not clear to me if by "long-term" you are referring specifically to something which is related to time or just to asymptotic behavior (where "long-term" would be interpreted as "much more observations").